# jquery autocomplete remote json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I was following the sample here:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/#&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog

I want to know how to adjust this section below:

```
   .then(function (response) {
                    $.each(response, function (i, val) {
                        html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                    });
                    $ul.html(html);
                    $ul.listview("refresh");
                    $ul.trigger("updatelayout");
                });
```

My JSON response is in the following format:

```
 {"directory": [
 {
 "firstname":"JOHN",
 "lastname":"DOE",
  "email":"user@domain.com",
  "ext":"1234",
   "dept":"ACME INC."
     }
   ]}
```

How do you access the json data in the **.then** function?

Cheers,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var response ={"directory": [
 {
 "firstname":"JOHN",
 "lastname":"DOE",
  "email":"user@domain.com",
  "ext":"1234",
   "dept":"ACME INC."
     }
   ]
              };

$.each(response.directory, function (i, val) {

    $.each(val, function (index, data) {

var         html = html+ "<li>" + data+ "</li>";
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I get the following error in Chrome:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

I have run my json through JsonLint and it is valid, so I am not sure what format jQuery is expecting.

Comment: It was my mistake.. was making a jsonp request instead of a json request.

Comment: if my aswer helps you,pls accept the answer to help the other find correct answer